# context.Response.Write(url) return content rather than text

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have some ajax request that is handled in httphandler

```
jQuery.ajax({ type: "GET", url: url, dataType: "text", complete: function (resp, status) {
                if (status == "success" || status == "notmodified")
                    if (resp.responseText != "error")
                        window.location = resp.responseText;
            }
        });
```

there is handler

```
    public class SocialNetworkUserLogin : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
      public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
             //verified something and
           context.Session["UnregUser"] = null;
           context.Response.Write(Config.SiteDomain + "/Registration.aspx");
}
}
```

when i check value of the resp.responseText it conteins Registration.aspx content
rather than url text for sample localhost:2101/Registration.aspx
please help understand is where i do mistake

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. You are saying that, when you invoke your AJAX method, then your browser will run into a 400 or 404 error saying that it cannot find the URL, because it is in fact being redirected to HTML markup instead of your URL?

Comment: if u want reproduct my code u can creat reproduce.ashx                       generic handler and copy my code above.For url u can use                                    var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath/reproduce.ashx

Comment: This is what I had already done, trying to reproduce. When I use this setup, with the line `window.location = resp.responseText` then it correctly opens the new url. I also tried just `alert(resp.responseText)` and that also just popped up a dialog displaying the url, not the page markup.

Comment: After posting that comment, I just had a thought: your `url` parameter is to "SocialNetworkUserLogin.ashx" and *not* to the result of the handler, right? If your `url` for the AJAX call is pointed to "Registration.aspx" then it *will* return the page markup in that case.

Comment: I too reproduce this code on localhost and it work fine,But when i 
try do it in real host server it return markup,I say about this issue 
my teamleader and he change something  and he say that old version 
but could not explain why this happened